# ClickOnce deployment for solution containing several projects

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, deployment, clickonce

I have a solution containing several projects, as well as some projects that get copied into subfolders relative to the main application. Is there any possibility to deploy this using ClickOnce? Or should i create a seperate project including references to my built files just for clickonce deployment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is the actual problem you are having?

Referenced assemblies are included automatically, and if I add an .EXE to a subfolder of my Project it shows up in the Application Files dialog of  Project|Publish.

Comment: Yes, that's what i also want to know. In the Clickonce settings for my main .exe, only the referenced files appear, but i also have a solution folder where plugins are located, and of course the main application doesn't have any reference to them. 

So should i add the output files of the plugins to a subfolder of my .exe?

Comment: Yes, just uses Add Existing item and set the filter to *.*

Comment: I was hoping there would be a way to separate the actual setup from the main executable, but that works just fine. thanks!